# Magento 2-2.2.5 Installation problem

Tags: installation, magento-2.2.5, centos

[image]Magento2 2.2.5 installed in centos7 server version when installation successfully completed and use my ip in browser it loading but magento setup page is not opening. I have set up a server with Nginx, PHP 7.1 and Mysql.

Comment: try to follow this [link](https://linuxize.com/post/install-magento-2-on-centos-7/) or this [one](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-2-on-centos-7/)

Comment: just check error logs

Answer (score 0):

Try again with this link. Make sure the php version is compatible with Magento 2
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html